# I can't compared the value of the GPIO state

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am starting working with python to control and read GPIO's for a simple tasks. I have the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

msg="Rememberto export the pin #"

# GPIO's
list = [4,27,16,12,21,22,23,10,9,13,11,20,5,6,18]

# MSG
msg="Status del PIN #"

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)

  
# Using for loop
for i in list[:]:
  GPIO.setup(i,GPIO.IN)
  try:
    with open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio"+str(i)+"/value") as pin:
      status = msg+str(i)+" = "+pin.read(1)
      #while True:
      if pin.read(1) == 0:
        cmd = "sudo php -q /var/www/html/index.php cron index/"+str(i)
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)

  except:
    print ("Debes exportar el PIN ", i)
    status = "Unknown"

  print (status)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

All works perfectly except for the following if statement:

```
if pin.read(1) == 0:
```

With the above I try to execute that IF when the value of GPIO is zero or I think it is False. I am stuck here for a while.

When I run the code I can see some Gpio's set 1 and some others 0.

Also tried with **if GPIO.input(i):** and **if not GPIO.input(i):** but I have not luck.

Can somebody help me on this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the output on stdout? Are you sure that the if statement is the problem? I'd recommend to remove the try/except or catch only a specific exception.

Comment: I am not sure if the statement is the problem because I am not python expert. Regarding stdout it's just executed when While True: is uncommented. I will test your suggestion removing try/catch.